# Is it true that a subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ is uncountable if and only if it contains an interval?

Tags: real-numbers

Is it true that a subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ is uncountable if and only if it contains an interval? I feel like this should be so but there could be some wonky counterexample.. Thanks!

edit: The motivation for my question comes form "An introduction to Mathematical Statistics and its Applications by Larsen and Marx".

***Definition 3.2.1:*** A real valued function whose domain is the sample space $S$ is called a random varaible.

The author continues:

"If the range of the mapping is either a finite or countably infinite number of values, the random variable is said to be discrete; if the range includes an interval of real numbers, bounded or unbounded, the random variable is said to be continuous"

Comment: What about the irrationals?

Comment: If you know any *countable* set which is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ then take that out and see what's left.

Comment: I edited my  question. Seems like the author didn't consider if a random variable had it's range as the irrationals when he defined a discrete random variable.

Comment: I can't speak specifically to this author, but it's pretty common for textbooks to leave a huge gap between purely atomic probability distributions and probability distributions that have a density, when first introducing this topic.  Those categories are by no means exhaustive, but it seems that you may need measure theory to make sense of some of the middle-ground...

Comment: I don't believe they were trying to make a general statement about subsets of the reals.  Most standard probability distributions have support that falls into one or the other type they mention.  That's all they mean.

Comment: Strictly speaking you can have $X:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ with $X([0,1]) = [0,1]$ but $P[X=0]=1$, so $X$ does not have a continuous CDF.  Take the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ as the probability measure, take any set $A\subseteq [0,1]$ with $P[A]=0$ but for which there is a bijective $h:A\rightarrow [0,1]$.  Define $$X(\omega) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} h(\omega) & \mbox{ if $\omega \in A$} \\ 0 & \mbox{ else} \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set.